# Gmod error darkrp lua script

Tags: lua

I need help with that LUA File but I dont have Edited this file it's a downloaded file.

The ADDON Pack is M9K Specialties, it's for GMOD Server.

|--------------------------------------------------------------------|

My ERROR Message is:

**[ERROR] gamemodes/darkrp/entities/weapons/m9k_davy_crockett/shared.lua:1: attempt to index a nil value
  1. unknown - gamemodes/darkrp/entities/weapons/m9k_davy_crockett/shared.lua:1**

Here is the File:

I just copie the 10 first lines, but the ERROR is in the Line: 1

```
1) if not (GetConVar("DavyCrockettAllowed"):GetBool()) then return end
2) -- Variables that are used on both client and server    
3) SWEP.Gun = ("m9k_davy_crockett") -- must be the name of your swep but NO CAPITALS!    
4) SWEP.Category                = "M9K Specialties"    
5) SWEP.Author              = ""    
6) SWEP.Contact             = ""    
7) SWEP.Purpose             = ""    
8) SWEP.Instructions                = ""
9) SWEP.MuzzleAttachment            = "1"   -- Should be "1" for CSS models or 10) "muzzle" for hl2 models    
10) SWEP.ShellEjectAttachment           = "2"   -- Should be "2" for CSS models or "1" for hl2 models
```

Comment: There isn't enough context there for anyone not familiar with GMOD to say much about what is going on but if that line one is in fact where the error is coming from then the problem is going to be in the GetConVar or GetBool functions and they are going to be attempting to operate on a table that doesn't contain the data they expect to be there. But again without more context and information I can't do more than guess.

Comment: How I can find more about this error?
I can do a download for only this shared.lua file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GetConVar` is apparentlu returning `nil`, and futher attempt to index it with `:` is what causing error. Review your docs - if this function is supposed to return `nil` in some cases, then you'll need to check return before trying to index it:

```
local DavyCrockettAllowed = GetConVar("DavyCrockettAllowed")
if not (DavyCrockettAllowed and DavyCrockettAllowed:GetBool()) then return end
```